# fread/fwrite introduces garbage values

Tags: c++, r, data.table, precision

Data file `data.dat`:

```
5625010350032.36719 5627008621379.12591 5628763999478.55791 5630383772880.98831 5632384688238.96095 5633992371569.87936 5635830220975.76879 5637713568911.67183 5639436594135.51215 5641160625591.58400 5643072053703.23919 5644920788572.33232 5646668772882.99855 5648398453919.33759 5650178043246.84799 5651842484825.03887 5653671759113.42399 5655374735235.55599 5657184594518.72287 5658951103084.33839 5660687853998.58127 5662491073242.24399
```

The following code

```
x1 <- data.matrix(data.table::fread("data.dat")) # Read it
plot(x1[1,])                                     
data.table::fwrite(x=x1, file="xout.dat", sep=" ") # Write it 
x2 <- data.matrix(data.table::fread("xout.dat"))   # Read it again
lines(x2[1,], col='red')
```

reveals that the element `x2[1,13]` takes the value `2.7898250541260385e-311` when it should in fact be equal to `x1[1,13]`. What is causing the garbage values to be introduced?

The `data.dat` file is written from a C++ file in the following way

```
    std::ofstream file("data.dat", std::ios::out);
    file << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10) << std::showpoint;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        file << v[i] << " ";
    file << std::endl;
```

where the vector `v` contains the values written to `data.dat`. I am using data.table version 1.14.2 and R 4.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appearantly it does some rounding somewhere in the process and fread stores that 13th value as `integer64` *"integer64" (default) reads columns detected as containing integers larger than 2^31 as type bit64::integer64*.

[image]

What you can do is force it to be interpretted as numeric, by adding `colClasses = c("numeric")` to your fread.

```
x2 <- data.matrix(data.table::fread("xout.dat", colClasses = c("numeric")))
```

This does not prevent the floating point issues but does not make the 13th value be changed completely.

If we now do x1-x2 we see for all values we have the same sort of differences.

```
x1-x2

#              V1         V2         V3         V4         V5          V6          V7        V8        V9       V10         V11       V12
# [1,] -0.0029297 -0.0039062 -0.0019531 -0.0019531 0.00097656 -0.00097656 -0.00097656 0.0019531 0.0019531 0.0039062 -0.00097656 0.0019531
#              V13        V14        V15         V16       V17        V18       V19         V20        V21       V22
# [1,] -0.00097656 -0.0019531 -0.0019531 -0.00097656 0.0039062 -0.0039062 0.0029297 -0.00097656 0.00097656 0.0039062
```

Comment: Can you expand "this does not prevent floating point issues"? It is odd that it can read to 16 place accuracy fine, but not write it to a file. For instance `write` works as expected, though I don't want the hassle of manually formatting etc. That is why we use packages like `data.table` in the first place. 
Also, my problem is not writing and re-reading _the same_ data - I am reading, performing an operation and then writing it again. I have been reading through the fwrite.c file but did not find anything interesting, only that maybe I write long doubles but fread reads doubles.

Comment: I think I wrote it wrong, not floating point issues but it seems fwrite stores the values rounded up with two digits after the dot. I am not sure how to prevent that.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems part of a bigger problem for me - in particular when there are a mix of data written in scientific and fixed point form.